# Series question - add or remove zeroes

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Is it true that if we remove from a number series a number of elements which are zeros (even infinitely many) that does not change its convergence and does not change its sum too (in the case when the series is convergent)?

I think the answer is yes (it follows easily if we look at the sequence of the partial sums) but I got confused in my thoughts somewhat so I need some confirmation.

I am not talking about series of functions, just about number series.

Comment: ?! How does it change it? BTW This is not a series but a sequence, right?

Comment: This is confusing, then how should I read this root test and ratio test if I assume the series may contain zeros https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/RootTest.aspx

Comment: Apparently I misread the question ...

Comment: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/RatioTest.aspx

Comment: How should I read these tests when the series contains zeros. Problems come up. So I was hoping I am allowed to remove all zeros, then apply the test?

Comment: So based on what is said in the question I was pointed to... It seems like the answer is yes. Right? Even though I still see a problem... if I remove an infinite number of elements which are zeros I may be left with a finite sum, not a series . But in that case I guess I don't need any convergence tests right? Since that means my initial series contained only a finite number of nonzero elements